# why linethrough in code of new Date

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I am using netbeans 7.2. the IDE is applying a line-through to a class name, what does it means and how can I resolve it?

```
Date cookiedate = new Date(timeStamp);
```

see the shot how its looking
[image]

Comment: usually that means it is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it means it's *deprecated*. See here for [more info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html).

> Java provides a way to express deprecation because, as a class
>   evolves, its API (application programming interface) inevitably
>   changes: methods are renamed for consistency, new and better methods
>   are added, and fields change. But such changes introduce a problem.
>   You need to keep the old API around until developers make the
>   transition to the new one, but you don't want them to continue
>   programming to the old API.
>
> The ability to deprecate a class, method, or member field solves the
>   problem.

I would suggest using [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead (with respect to the suggestions made by other posters here), since the `Date`/`Calendar` stuff that isn't deprecated is such a pain to use (non-untuitive api, mutable, thread-unsafe)

Answer (score 1):

```
new Date(timeStamp);
```

You are using parameterized constructor of Date class which is deprecated, so you see that line cross. In fact most of the methods of `Date` class is now deprecated.

See documentation of [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class which clearly marks the parameterized constructor as `Deprecated`.

> Date(String s) 
>   Deprecated.  
>   As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   DateFormat.parse(String s).

I would rather suggest to use [**`Joda Time API`**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) if you want to **make your life easier** while working with `Dates`.

Answer (score 0):

It means the API you are invoking is deprecated, you should use Calendar API for example or if you are looking for a more sophisticated API I suggest to use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Linethrough means it is deprecated. There is some other class/method available in place of that class/method. And also Netbeans shows somewhere around that deprecated class/method what you can use use instead of it if you have javadoc set up in it